# Is storing info in unrelated attached properties a code smell?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I was just watching a "how-to" type WPF video called [How Do I: Use Attached Properties to Store Extra Data in WPF](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=32300), and it was describing what to do when you want to associate two pieces of information with a single control.  If you want to put one piece of information in, they say to use the Tag property.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Tag="innerData">
</Grid>
```

Fair enough.

But then they say, "what happens if you want to store a second piece of data, say, an integer?"  The solution, they say is to use an unused attached property.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Tag="innerData" Canvas.Top="55">
</Grid>
```

They say because it's in a Grid, no problem!  I say "Bleh!"  This strikes me as extremely nasty...and quite misleading to read.  Is this common practice?

Comment: "They say because it's in a Grid, no problem!" - I have a bit of womit in my mouth after that one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quick and easy but it's definitely preferable to define your own Attached Properties or custom control to handle these situations. This is the type of thing that's okay for prototypes or quick one-off apps but shouldn't be done if the code is going to have a real lifespan that will require maintenance down the road.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, for one-off apps that you're going to throw away, sure; anything goes, right?  But I'm talking about real applications; I mean, this was the whole point of the video: "How Do I: Use Attached Properties to Store Extra Data in WPF" and this was the answer.  Struck me as ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a smell.

I'm not sure if it is common -- I've never seen it before.

Frankly, I find `Tag` to be a framework-endorsed smell itself.

Comment: I agree, but I've seen it often enough that I've accepted it.  This seemed worse to me because Tag doesn't really have any connotation to it, while Canvas.Top definitely does.

Answer (score 1):

Not a best practice.

I am always of the opinion, code (including Xaml) is written to be human readable.

It would take quite a bit of research to figure out who is using that property, and for what.

Answer (score 0):

This technique can be a real time-saver.  Use of it tells you, "I shouldn't waste any more time studying these training materials."